# NumPy: How to calulate piecewise linear interpolant on multiple axes

Tags: numpy, linear-interpolation

Given the following ndarray `t` -

```
In [26]: t.shape                                                                                     
Out[26]: (3, 3, 2)

In [27]: t                                                                                           
Out[27]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])
```

this piecewise linear interpolant for the points `t[:, 0, 0]` can evaluated for `[0 , 0.66666667, 1.33333333, 2.]` as follows using [numpy.interp](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html?highlight=interp#numpy.interp) -

```
In [38]: x = np.linspace(0, t.shape[0]-1, 4)                                                         

In [39]: x                                                                                           
Out[39]: array([0.        , 0.66666667, 1.33333333, 2.        ])

In [30]: xp = np.arange(t.shape[0])                                                                  

In [31]: xp                                                                                          
Out[31]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [32]: fp = t[:,0,0]                                                                               

In [33]: fp                                                                                          
Out[33]: array([ 0,  6, 12])

In [40]: np.interp(x, xp, fp)                                                                        
Out[40]: array([ 0.,  4.,  8., 12.])
```

How can all the interpolants be efficiently calculated and returned together for all values of `fp` -

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the interpolation is 1d with changing `y` values it must be run for each 1d slice of t.  It's probably faster to loop explicitly but neater to loop using np.apply_along_axis

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange( 18 ).reshape(3,3,2)

x = np.linspace( 0, t.shape[0]-1, 4)
xp = np.arange(t.shape[0])


def interfunc( arr ):
    """ Function interpolates a 1d array. """
    return np.interp( x, xp, arr )

np.apply_along_axis( interfunc, 0, t ) # apply function along axis 0

"""  Result
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  9.]],

       [[ 8.,  9.],
        [10., 11.],
        [12., 13.]],

       [[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.],
        [16., 17.]]]) """
```

With explicit loops

```
result = np.zeros((4,3,2))
for c in range(t.shape[1]):
    for p in range(t.shape[2]):
       result[:,c,p] = np.interp( x, xp, t[:,c,p])
```

On my machine the second option runs in half the time.

**Edit to use `np.nditer`**

As the result and the parameter have different shapes I seem to have to create two np.nditer objects one for the parameter and one for the result. This is my first attempt to use `nditer` for anything so it could be over complicated.

```
def test( t ):                                                              
    ts = t.shape              
    result = np.zeros((ts[0]+1,ts[1],ts[2]))
    param = np.nditer( [t], ['external_loop'], ['readonly'],  order = 'F')
    with np.nditer( [result], ['external_loop'], ['writeonly'],  order = 'F') as res:       
        for p, r in zip( param, res ):
            r[:] = interfunc(p)
    return result
```

It's slightly slower than the explicit loops and less easy to follow than either of the other solutions.

Comment: @Tis Chris I notice you use standard python looping techniques to iterate over the second and third axes of `t`. Is there any benefit to using `numpy.nditer`?

Comment: @user2309803 I spent some time experimenting with `nditer`. I've avoided it due to the documentation length :-)  The solution seems clumsier than either of the others but for the data here ran very slightly slower than he explicit loop.   I'm not sure there are any gains from `nditer` in this context.  Perhaps I've missed something in my implementation though.

Comment: @Tis Chris: I managed to re-implement your solution using `np.nditer(t[0], flags=['multi_index'])` but it was 10% slower.

Comment: @user2309803: Can you post as a solution. I've never really tried to understand `nditer` or found a problem that I thought it would help with.  It would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @Tis Chris, here is a solution using `np.nditer` with the `multi_index` flag but I prefer the explicit nested `for` loops method above because it is 10% faster

```
In [29]: t = np.arange( 18 ).reshape(3,3,2)                                                          

In [30]: ax0old = np.arange(t.shape[0])                                                              

In [31]: ax0new = np.linspace(0, t.shape[0]-1, 4)                                                    

In [32]: tnew = np.zeros((len(ax0new), t.shape[1], t.shape[2]))                                      

In [33]: it = np.nditer(t[0], flags=['multi_index'])                                                 

In [34]: for _ in it: 
    ...:     tnew[:, it.multi_index[0], it.multi_index[1]] = np.interp(ax0new, ax0old, t[:, it.multi_
    ...: index[0], it.multi_index[1]]) 
    ...:                                                                                             

In [35]: tnew                                                                                        
Out[35]: 
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  9.]],

       [[ 8.,  9.],
        [10., 11.],
        [12., 13.]],

       [[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.],
        [16., 17.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've a clearer idea how that works now.  I have code that performs the interpolation along any chosen axis of the source array.  I'm wondering if nditer can speed it up or make it clearer,

Answer (score 0):

You could try `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

 t = np.array([[[ 0,  1],
                [ 2,  3],
                [ 4,  5]],

               [[ 6,  7],
                [ 8,  9],
                [10, 11]],

               [[12, 13],
                [14, 15],
                [16, 17]]])

# for the first slice
f = interp1d(np.arange(t.shape[0]), t[..., 0], axis=0)
# returns a function which you call with values within range np.arange(t.shape[0])

# data used for interpolation
t[..., 0]
>>> array([[ 0,  2,  4],
           [ 6,  8, 10],
           [12, 14, 16]])

f(1)
>>> array([ 6.,  8., 10.])

f(1.5)
>>> array([ 9., 11., 13.])
```